# При установке Python выходит ошибка 0x80070643

Tags: python, установка

[image: Ошибка]

Устанавливаю Python с официального сайта. Выходит такая ошибка. Пробовал удалить весь Python с компьютера и переустановить, чистил реестр. Уже второй день мучаюсь с ошибкой. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы исправить это. P.S Пробовал установить несколько версий Python, везде такая фигня. Мб я удалил случайно ,какие-либо системные файлы? И как их восстановить. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Судя по https://bugs.python.org/issue32966 действительно, как вариант, можно почистить систему от уже установленных питонов. А установщик пробовали от админа запускать?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу данной ошибки можно найти [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32966) на python.org.

Основные тезисы для решения данной проблемы:

1. Обновления Windows. Установите все обновления, перезагрузите при необходимости. Объяснения такие, что может происходить еще одна установка, которая не может быть контролируема на 100%. Также, это известная проблема и на момент (22.04.2020) не может быть решена с помощью установщика `Python`.
2. Если была установлена ранее одна из версий Python (issue относится к версиям 3.7.2 и 3.8), а затем удалена, то рекомендация относится к тому, что необходимо восстановить старую версию (если это возможно), а затем удалить ее. После чего устанавливать новую. В данном случае идет отсылка `PATH`. То есть почистить переменные окружения тоже может быть не лишним

Answer (score 0):

Удалите из переменных окружения ОС всё, что связано с Python. Найдите в папке windows файлы py.exe, pyw.exe и удалите их.

Answer (score 0):

Привeтcтвyю, была похожая проблема на нетбуке (Samsung-np-nc110-p05ru, win 8.1 x32 Home Premium) при установке версии **3.9.13**(x32). Решилась выбором версии **3.8.8**(x32). Думаю, что это как-то может быть связано с тем, что некоторые новые версии не поддерживают win 7